# insert Single Quotation Marks in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update, sql-insert

I want to insert " exec e_Report.dbo.FTX_FA_Aging_Report_sp 'FACloedAgingReport' " in AlertSQL columns in my existing table.

How will be my update script?

My script for update is as below:

```
update dbo.F_ALERT
    set AlertSQL= 'exec e_Report.dbo.FTX_FA_Aging_Report_sp '''FACloedAgingReport''
        where AlertID=9330
```

Some how its not giving me expected result.
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s sql server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your quote positioning. You need a pair of single quotes at either end of the quoted string, as well as the quotes for the whole query.

```
'exec ee_Report.dbo.FTX_FA_Aging_Report_sp ''FACloedAgingReportSee'''
```

Currently you have three before and two after, it should be the other way around as per Gordon's answer.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178070

Comment: Have you tried it on sql server 2008 (like question is tagged)?

Comment: The question wasn't tagged when the answer was written

Comment: @QuantumTiger  how will be the insert statement if its sql 2000? will it be different?

Comment: This may be of help https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224033(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need more quotes and things:

```
update dbo.F_ALERT
    set AlertSQL= 'exec e_Report.dbo.FTX_FA_Aging_Report_sp ''FACloedAgingReport'''
        where AlertID = 9330 ;
```

It is a bit confusing, but `''''` is a string with a single quote.  Two single quotes together are a single single quote.  Hence:

```
'exec e_Report.dbo.FTX_FA_Aging_Report_sp ''FACloedAgingReport'''
^ starts a string
------------------------------------------^ two quotes are single quote in the string
--------------------------------------------------------------^ two quotes are single quote in the string and then one more to end the string itself
```